# Creating a table with multiple records from one table based on a second table

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to take several records from a daily file and list all the dates  for several tanks (there can be up to 5) on a single line per customer. there are also other related fields that need to be carried along with the date I have show pulldown here but there is also another field liters that needs to appear.  I would prefer that they be in separate fields so I can put them into a grid to allow for separate sorting ..

table a

```
custid, tankid, filldate, pulldown  

1        2      01/01/12   1/2  
1        3      01/01/12   3/4  
2        4      01/02/12   2/3  
2        5      01/03/12   1/2  
1        2      02/01/12   2/3
```

table b

```
custid tankid
1        2
1        3
1        7
2        5
2        4
2        6
```

output

```
custid tankid1  date1   pulldown1 tankid2   date 2   pulldown2   tankid3 ...    
1       2      01/01/12    1/2      3      01/01/12    3/4          7
1       2      02/01/12    2/3      3                               7
2       4      01/02/12    2/3      5                               6
2       4                           5      01/03/12    1/2          6
```

Thanks

Scott

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. 
Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? 
Show your effort first so people might show theirs. 
Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start..

Comment: Thanks for your comment ... I have read through and tried all the options regarding combining multiple rows into one such as merging, xml path.. but not seems to be able to combine that many fields into separate fields when dealing with not only two tables but two tables and multiple records from one table.. I have been working on this for now three days.. and have come to this group for help.. thanks